# Google Contacts API 401 Authorization Required android

Tags: android, google-contacts-api

I am trying to fetch list of contacts using Google API and I have tried,

```
String url = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full";

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("response",response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.d("error",error!=null?error.getMessage():"unknown error");
    }
});
```

But I am getting `401`. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

401 error is related to [401: Invalid Credentials](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors#401_invalid_credentials). You need to be authorized using OAuth.

Follow the [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#authorizing_requests_with_oauth_20)

> Requests to the Google Contacts API for non-public user data must be
>   authorized by an authenticated user.
>
> The details of the authorization process, or "flow," for OAuth 2.0
>   vary somewhat depending on what kind of application you're writing.
>   The following general process applies to all application types:
>
> 1. When you create your application, you register it with Google. Google then provides information you'll need later, such as a client
>      ID and a client secret.
> 2. Activate the Google Contacts API in the Services pane of the Google APIs Console. (If it isn't listed in the Console, then skip this
>      step.)
> 3. When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular scope of access. Publicly available applications with
>      access to certain user data must pass review. If you see an access
>      error for your app, submit a request using our OAuth Developer
>      Verification form. For personal-use apps and those you are testing,
>      join the Google group Risky Access Permissions By Unreviewed Apps,
>      which allows you to approve data access with your personal and testing
>      accounts. Members of this group can grant unverified apps access to
>      their data. See the Google API Services User Data Policy for more
>      information.
>
> Publicly available applications with access to certain user data must
>   pass review. If you see an access error for your app, submit a request
>   using our OAuth Developer Verification form.
>
> 1. Google displays an OAuth dialog to the user, asking them to authorize your application to request some of their data. If the user
>      approves, then Google gives your application a short-lived access
>      token.
> 2. Your application requests user data, attaching the access token to the request.
> 3. If Google determines that your request and the token are valid, it returns the requested data.

Comment: i have enabled Contact API from Google API console and i have also added required scopes . OAuth dialog appears and after that i got access token also . but when i try to get contacts after then 401 problem occurs..

Comment: can you suggest me how to get Google+ circles and their followers ??  this can also solve my problem......